# Most Durable Wired Mouse

Tags: mouse

I've seen this question asked many times on message boards, but the answer is usually "my mouse has been great for years."

However, I've never heard any TECHNICAL reason why one mouse brand/model is more durable than another.

====

**Is there any wired mouse built with stronger materials, that increases durability?**

Specifically, the scroll wheel and left/right clicking mechanisms.

Comment: IMHO, Logitech builds the best mice.

Comment: I have an old Logitech M-UV96 that refuses to die.

Comment: I *destroy* equipment I touch, but *all* my Logitech stuff is still around.

Comment: No wait, I lie. My wireless keyboard is a bit flaky, probably from dropping it a few too many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the perspective of an industrial pundit, there is no substitute for R&D and testing.

The reason that people seem to compliment Logitech mice and keyboards (along with Microsoft's mice, lately) is that they have experience and put years of research into this. The only way to get past this vicious/virtuous cycle (depending on your perspective) is to find more efficient ways of research and testing or to by chance find the secret to durability.

Also, keeping the mouse in one place and taking care of it helps too.

Comment: Thank you, this was the kind of technical answer I was looking for. --- I too have had good luck with Logitech and I think you may be right about research.